# wSolving non-linear equations using fsolve in Matlab

Tags: matlab, optimization, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization

I have to solve a system of non-linear equations of the following function:

```
function eq = ts_7(A,B,C,D,E)
syms x 
% dbstop if error

g = D * sin(C * atan( B*x - E * (B*x - atan(B*x)))) + A; % magic formula
eq5 = taylor(g, x, 'Order',1, 'ExpansionPoint',7) + 4296; % x^0
eq1 = taylor(g, x, 'Order',2, 'ExpansionPoint',7) - eq5 + 296.3; % x^1
eq2 = taylor(g, x, 'Order',3, 'ExpansionPoint',7) - eq1 - 79.77; % x^2
eq3 = taylor(g, x, 'Order',4, 'ExpansionPoint',7) - eq2 - 4.541; % x^3
eq4 = taylor(g, x, 'Order',5, 'ExpansionPoint',7) - eq3 - 0.03358; % x^4

eq{1} = matlabFunction(eq1) % syms to numeric function
eq{2} = matlabFunction(eq2)
eq{3} = matlabFunction(eq3)
eq{4} = matlabFunction(eq4)
eq{5} = matlabFunction(eq5)
end
```

and my main is the following

```
opts = optimoptions('fsolve','InitDamping',0.005,'Algorithm','levenberg-marquardt');
init = [-1.3, 1.4, 4000, 0.12, 9]; % starting points 
tic
coeff = fsolve(@(x)ts_7(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5)), init,opts);
toc
```

and the error I keep getting is

> Undefined function or variable "fuser".
>
> Error in fsolve (line 257)
>   if ~isempty( isoptimargdbl('FSOLVE', {'F','J'}, fuser, JAC) )
>
> Error in script_7 (line 11)
>   coeff = fsolve(@(x)ts_7(x(1), x(2), x(3), x(4), x(5)), init,opts);
>
> Error in run (line 96)
>   evalin('caller', [script ';']);

I don't know how to fix it. I also tried solving the same problem with `vpasolve` and `solve`. For `solve`, it takes too long and for `vpasolve`, I get the error that symbolic parameters are not allowed in a non-poly equation.

Is there a way to transform string into a function (not a handle function what `matlabFunction` is doing in this code)?

I am getting desperate because I don't want to rewrite everything by hand.

UPDATE: I tried solving 2-D system, example from  http://nl.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html. I get the same error, here is the screenshot. [image]

Answer (score 2):

Your function `ts_7` needs to return a floating point vector, but `eq` is a cell array of function handles. You also don't need to call `matlabFunction` five time. Instead:

```
eq = matlabFunction([eq1;eq2;eq3;eq4;eq5]);
```

Now `eq` is a function handle that returns a 5-by-1 column vector of doubles. This needs to be evaluated numerically at the expansion point `x` so that the output of `ts_7` is a floating point vector, for example:

```
eq = eq(1);
```

It's not clear to me if you're also optimizing `x` or if you know this.

Comment: I know x, it is an array of doubles, 341x1. Let's say I have an equation 
eq5 = taylor(g, x, 'Order',1, 'ExpansionPoint',7) + 4296(x-7).
Do I have to pass x or I just set it to be 8 so that (x-7) = 1 and thus we neutralise it.

Comment: I tried running the code with your modification but it is not a column vector but a 1x1 function handle.
Moreover I get the same error. Is there a way how to convert syms to a regular function, not a handle function?

Comment: "Do I have to pass x or I just set it to be 8 so that (x-7) = 1 and thus we neutralise it." –  I don't know what problem you're trying to solve or what `x` is so I can't answer that sort of thing.

Comment: "I tried running the code with your modification but it is not a column vector but a 1x1 function handle." – Sorry, the wording of my answer was a bit unclear. I'm using the code in your question. I've edited my answer to clarify what `eq` returned by `matlabFunction([eq1;eq2;eq3;eq4;eq5])` is.

Comment: "Is there a way how to convert syms to a regular function, not a handle function?" – What's wrong with a function handle? It is possible to write the function to a file, but that's not really necessary. I recommend reading the documentation for `matlabFunction`.

Comment: "I don't know what problem you're trying to solve or what x is so I can't answer that sort of thing. " 
- I need to find coefficients A, B, C, D and E. x is not important in this case.

Comment: I have another error: Error using fsolve (line 257)
FSOLVE requires all values returned by user functions to be of data type double.

Answer (score 0):

There was something wrong with my MATLAB. I solved the problem by using another version of MATLAB.